# Why is my Swift Process() launch path spitting out `launch path not accessible`?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, swift5, macos-catalina

```swift
            Button(action: {
                let installNano = Process()
                installNano.launchPath = "/opt/pkg/bin/pkgin"
                installNano.launch()
            }) {
            Text("Run pkgin")
            }
```

I'm trying to make it so when this button is pressed it'll launch the pkgin binary and when the login binary is ran it should display this help page:

```
Usage: pkgin [-cdfFhlnPtvVy] command [package ...]

Commands and shortcuts:
list                (ls  ) - List installed local packages
avail               (av  ) - List all available remote packages
search              (se  ) - Search for a remote package
install             (in  ) - Install or upgrade packages
update              (up  ) - Refresh local and remote package lists
upgrade             (ug  ) - Upgrade only packages marked with the keep flag
full-upgrade        (fug ) - Upgrade all packages
remove              (rm  ) - Remove packages and any dependent packages
keep                (ke  ) - Mark packages that should be kept
unkeep              (uk  ) - Mark packages that can be autoremoved
export              (ex  ) - Display PKGPATH for all keep packages
import              (im  ) - Import keep package list from file
show-keep           (sk  ) - Display keep packages
show-no-keep        (snk ) - Display autoremovable packages
autoremove          (ar  ) - Remove orphaned dependencies
clean               (cl  ) - Remove downloaded package files
show-deps           (sd  ) - List remote package direct dependencies
show-full-deps      (sfd ) - List remote package full dependencies
show-rev-deps       (srd ) - List local package reverse dependencies
provides            (prov) - Show which shared libraries a package provides
requires            (req ) - Show which shared libraries a package requires
show-category       (sc  ) - List all packages belonging to a category
show-pkg-category   (spc ) - Show categories a package belongs to
show-all-categories (sac ) - List all known categories
pkg-content         (pc  ) - Show remote package content
pkg-descr           (pd  ) - Show remote package long-description
pkg-build-defs      (pbd ) - Show remote package build definitions
stats               (st  ) - Show local and remote package statistics
```

but instead it spits out this error in the `All Output` pane on Xcode:

```
2019-09-16 18:00:56.152377-0700 Jupiter[7507:210600] [General] launch path not accessible
2019-09-16 18:00:56.156127-0700 Jupiter[7507:210600] [General] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2eb49a43 __exceptionPreprocess + 250
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff64daf8f3 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   Foundation                          0x00007fff3122d681 -[NSConcreteTask launchWithDictionary:error:] + 5234
    3   Jupiter                             0x0000000100001dcd $s7Jupiter11ContentViewV4bodyQrvg7SwiftUI05TupleC0VyAE6ButtonVyAE4TextVG_ALtGyXEfU_yycfU_ + 141
    4   SwiftUI                             0x00007fff3bc2fd09 $s7SwiftUI33PrimitiveButtonStyleConfigurationV7triggeryyF + 25
    5   SwiftUI                             0x00007fff3c07f510 $s7SwiftUI33PrimitiveButtonStyleConfigurationV7triggeryyFTA + 16
    6   SwiftUI                             0x00007fff3c07eeb9 $s7SwiftUI11Coordinator33_9FEBA96B0BC70E1682E82D239F242E73LLC14didPressButtonyySo8NSButtonCF + 25
    7   SwiftUI                             0x00007fff3c07eef6 $s7SwiftUI11Coordinator33_9FEBA96B0BC70E1682E82D239F242E73LLC14didPressButtonyySo8NSButtonCFTo + 38
    8   AppKit                              0x00007fff2bf74434 -[NSApplication(NSResponder) sendAction:to:from:] + 299
    9   AppKit                              0x00007fff2bfd3a30 -[NSControl sendAction:to:] + 86
    10  AppKit                              0x00007fff2bfd3962 __26-[NSCell _sendActionFrom:]_block_invoke + 136
    11  AppKit                              0x00007fff2bfd3864 -[NSCell _sendActionFrom:] + 171
    12  AppKit                              0x00007fff2bffbb17 -[NSButtonCell _sendActionFrom:] + 96
    13  AppKit                              0x00007fff2c3652a4 NSControlTrackMouse + 1745
    14  AppKit                              0x00007fff2bfd227c -[NSCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 130
    15  AppKit                              0x00007fff2bffb880 -[NSButtonCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 691
    16  AppKit                              0x00007fff2bfd1512 -[NSControl mouseDown:] + 748
    17  AppKit                              0x00007fff2bec4049 -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) _handleMouseDownEvent:isDelayedEvent:] + 4907
    18  AppKit                              0x00007fff2be075d8 -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) _reallySendEvent:isDelayedEvent:] + 2612
    19  AppKit                              0x00007fff2be06961 -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) sendEvent:] + 349
    20  AppKit                              0x00007fff2bcc9b64 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) sendEvent:] + 352
    21  AppKit                              0x00007fff2bcb93c6 -[NSApplication run] + 707
    22  AppKit                              0x00007fff2bcab1c6 NSApplicationMain + 777
    23  Jupiter                             0x0000000100005bfd main + 13
    24  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff661022a5 start + 1
    25  ???                                 0x0000000000000003 0x0 + 3
)
```

I don't understand why it gives me the `launch path not accessible` error because I've checked that launch path I'm using multiple times and the path and everything is there on my computer so it doesn't make any sense to me why this isn't working. When using `Command + Shift + G` and enter the launch path it takes me into the folder and selects the `pkgin` so everything is definitely 100% there which is what confuses me since if everything is there the path should be working. If you have any idea on why this isn't working anything helps.

Comment: I suspect that has something to do with app sandboxing,  security measure. I know Catalina added in a bunch of new security measures, look into those.

Comment: @Alexander the sandbox entitlement is set to yes, I guess I could try changing that.

Comment: @Alexander yup the sandbox was the issue! Post what you said as an answer so I can mark it as the solution.

Comment: You should write precisely what you did as an answer, and accept your own answer. I didn't really do much.

Answer (score 1):

I just had to go to entitlements for my app and set the sandbox from YES to NO to fix the problem.